# Multiple mutexes in same struct?

Tags: go, struct, concurrency, mutex

I have a few related questions about Go's `sync.Mutex` used with `struct`. If I  were to, for instance, have this `struct`:

```
type something struct {
    aMux sync.Mutex
    a    map[string]interface{}

    bMux sync.Mutex
    b    int
}
```

... **would it be safe to lock `bMux` and access `b` while concurrently locking `aMux` and accessing `a` without a race condition?**

It's probably also helpful to know that I'm accessing pointers to the structs, and using methods like this to lock/unlock the mutexes concurrently:

```
func (s *something) addA(k string, v interface{}) {
    (*s).aMux.Lock()
    (*s).a[k] = v
    (*s).aMux.Unlock()
}

func (s *something) addB(k string, v interface{}) {
    (*s).bMux.Lock()
    (*s).b++
    (*s).bMux.Unlock()
}
```

My assumption is that this should theoretically be safe, since you can already lock a mutex in a struct without having to access the field(s) it locks. **But when dereferencing a `struct` like above, does Go copy all the values from the `struct` (making it unsafe), or does it only modify/retrieve the fields you specify?**

I would very much like to keep the mutexes in the same struct, since in my code I have multiple (up to six) related fields in the same struct that I lock separately with mutexes. **If having multiple mutexes in the same struct (for related fields) is safe, but not recommended or bad practice, why? What would be a better structure?**

Comment: @Adrian: you could be kinder to a beginner. Since `s` is a pointer it's reasonable to want to dereference it unless you know Go can do this automagically in some cases. It certainly doesn't make the code nonsensical

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be safe to have multiple mutexes in a single struct. Just be careful not to pass the struct by value because mutexes are not reference types and copying them is wrong (see [this discussion](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2018/beware-of-copying-mutexes-in-go/) for more details).

You do not need the explicit dereferencing, Go does it for you:

```
func (s *something) addA(k string, v interface{}) {
    s.aMux.Lock()
    s.a[k] = v
    s.aMux.Unlock()
}
```

Should work just as well (it's in the [Go tour](https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/4)).

I would say it's not very usual design though. I'd prefer a mutex to lock the whole structure if possible. Once you're doing very fine grained locking you have to be extremely careful, and I would explore other options first.

Answer (score 3):

- Yes you can have more than one mutex in your structs
- Don't over-complicate things: you can use a single mutex to protect access to either of the two elements in your struct i.e. any operation that modifies your `map` or `int` could share the same single mutex
- When referencing your struct from other functions - use pointers like your methods are doing - to ensure the struct is not copied. Copied structs - with mutexs - will lead to unpredictable/unsafe results

From the golang [mutex docs](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex):

> Values containing the types defined in this package (i.e. sync.Mutux) should not be copied.